# Gridland Metro HackerRank

Tags: java, algorithm, optimization, data-structures, greedy

I was solving this [question](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/gridland-metro/problem) on hackerRank. I have gone through the whole discussions section, tried all the suggested test cases with expected results. I think I might be doing some silly code mistake as I'm sure I've thought/considered every scenario in the implementation. could you please help me out pointing if there is any mistake in my code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String strNum[] = bf.readLine().split("\\s");
    double n = Double.parseDouble(strNum[0]);
    double m = Double.parseDouble(strNum[1]);
    double k = Double.parseDouble(strNum[2]);

    Map<Double, TreeMap<Double, Double>> map = new HashMap<>();
    while (k > 0) {
        strNum = bf.readLine().split("\\s");
        double r = Double.parseDouble(strNum[0]);
        double c1 = Double.parseDouble(strNum[1]);
        double c2 = Double.parseDouble(strNum[2]);
        TreeMap<Double, Double> innerMap = map.get(r);
        if (innerMap != null) {
            Double x = innerMap.get(c1);
            if (x != null) {
                if (c2 > x) {
                    innerMap.put(c1, c2);
                }
            } else {
                innerMap.put(c1, c2);
            }
        } else {
            innerMap = new TreeMap<Double, Double>();
            innerMap.put(c1, c2);
            map.put(r, innerMap);
        }
        k--;
    }
    double count = (n - map.size()) * m;
    for (Map.Entry<Double, TreeMap<Double, Double>> e : map.entrySet()) {
        TreeMap<Double, Double> innerMap = e.getValue();
        double start = innerMap.firstKey();
        double end = innerMap.firstEntry().getValue();
        for (Map.Entry<Double, Double> e2 : innerMap.entrySet()) {
            double x = e2.getKey();
            double y = e2.getValue();
            if (y > end) {
                if (x > end) {
                    count += ((x - end) - 1);
                }
                end = y;
            }
        }
        count += (m - (end - start + 1));
    }
    System.out.println(String.format("%.0f", count));
}
```

24/31 test cases are failing. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Without going into the details, the challenge description specifies that the inputs are Integers, however you are handling them as doubles. That right away might be the root of many of your issues since math with doubles is not recommended.

Comment: It seems to be failing the following test case: 1 1 1 then 1 1 1. It's supposed to return 1, but returns 0.

Comment: Also, before you start looking for the solution, after the user input, you need to add a edge validation, something like :         if (n < 1 || m < 1 || k < 1 || map.isEmpty()) {
            return 0;
        }

Comment: @fpezzini for 111,111 it should return 0. because there is only  a single cell. which is also a train track. So no cell is available for lamppost and hence result should be 0.

Comment: Ahh, good point. It seems you're pretty close, I'd say think of possible edge cases, some of the unit tests will check for that (like my commend above).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@fpezzini has a point about doubles: on the input

```
1000000000 1000000000 1
1 1 1
```

your code prints `1000000000000000000`, not `999999999999999999`, because the latter cannot be represented as a double.

Comment: I have a question though! how come a double can store 1000000000000000000 (19 digits) but not 999999999999999999 (18 digits) ?

Comment: @saurabhgupta Double is designed to store numbers much bigger than Long can, using the same number of bits. In consequence, big numbers get rounded more and more aggressively. IEEE 754 (the standard that Java Doubles follow) uses binary, but as an analogy, I can write 1000000000000000000 as 1e18 using only four characters in scientific notation, but I can't write 999999999999999999 that concisely.

Answer (score 1):

If your code reads `r,c1,c2` followed by `r,c1,c2'` with `c2'<c2`, it'll silently drop the former track.

Comment: It won't as there is a condition (if(y>end)) which in your case y=c2' and end=c2 , which only executes if c2' >c2

Comment: @saurabhgupta IIRC TreeMap isn't a multimap -- it gets dropped while reading the input.

Comment: give me a test case and I'll see whether this code is producing the expected output or not.

Comment: @saurabhgupta 1 row, 2 columns, tracks 1 1 2 and 1 1 1 in that order.

Comment: The answer is 0 because the first track occupies all of the squares, but I think your code will produce 1.

Comment: see the updated question, I've handled that but still, 24/31 test cases are failing.